# Efficient deletion of specific list entries

Tags: list-manipulation, sets

It is sometimes useful to remove exactly the amount of specific entries on one list from another.

Consider:

```
CountingComplement[{1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 3, 4, 5}, {6, 1, 3, 1, 5}]
```

> {2, 1, 3, 4}

Two `1`s and one of the other entries are deleted from the first list, unlike with `Complement` which would remove every instance of `1`, for instance.

I have a reasonably pretty, but obviously not very efficient implementation of this function:

```
ClearAll@CountingComplement;

CountingComplement = Fold[Delete[#, FirstPosition[##, {}]] &];
```

Are there any reasonable elegant alternatives to this function which repeatedly reconstructs the resulting list?

Comment: Is it essential to preserve the order of the remaining element?

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Maybe it's not essential, but it probably would be nice in some applications to maintain the order. Non-order-preserving solutions are fine too.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a solution that reorders elements.

```
a = {1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 3, 4, 5};
b = {6, 1, 3, 1, 5};

CountingComplement[a_, b_] := Module[{ca, cb},
  ca = Counts[a];
  cb = Counts[b];
  Do[ca[i] = Ramp[ca[i] - cb[i]], {i, Intersection[Keys[ca], Keys[cb]]}];
  Join @@ ConstantArray @@@ Normal[ca]
  ]

CountingComplement[a, b]
```

> {1, 2, 3, 4}

Comment: Similar and  shorter: Flatten@KeyValueMap[Table]@
  Merge[Apply@Subtract]@KeyUnion[{Counts@a, Counts@b}, 0 &]

Answer (score 7):

This will maintain order but is notably slower than the method provided by @HenrikSchumacher. The idea is to create down values of counts for the second list, then decrement said counts when they appear in the first and remove corresponding elements in the first, until a count goes to zero. Retain all else in the first list.

```
complementByCount[l1_, l2_] := Module[{c2, cval},
  Scan[If[Head[c2[#]] === c2, c2[#] = 1, c2[#]++] &, l2];
  Map[(cval = c2[#];
     If[IntegerQ[cval] && cval > 0, c2[#]--; Nothing,(*else*)#]) &
   , l1]]
```

Check:

```
In[182]:= complementByCount[{1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 3, 4, 5}, {6, 1, 3, 1, 5}]

(* Out[182]= {2, 1, 3, 4} *)
```

Here is a larger example.

```
l1 = RandomInteger[{-1000, 1000}, 10000];
l2 = RandomInteger[{-1000, 1000}, 10000];

Timing[cbc = complementByCount[l1, l2];]

(* Out[181]= {0.25, Null} *)
```

The method provided by @Henrik is an order of magnitude or so faster (I changed the name to lower case since that's a common custom, but otherwise left the code as is).

```
In[162]:= Timing[cbc2 = countingComplement[l1, l2];]

(* Out[162]= {0.03125, Null} *)
```

The results agree up to reordering:

```
In[177]:= Sort[cbc2] === Sort[cbc]

(* Out[177]= True *)
```

Answer (score 6):

Short but not efficient:

```
f = Fold[DeleteCases[##, 1, 1] &];


{a, b} = {{1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 3, 4, 5}, {6, 1, 3, 1, 5}};
f[a, b]
```

> {2, 1, 3, 4}

Slightly longer and faster:

```
f2 = Fold[DeleteCases[#,  First @ #2, 1, UpTo @ Last @ #2] &, #, Tally @ #2]&;
f2[a, b]
```

> {2, 1, 3, 4}

An internal function that seems to be as fast as Henrik's `CountingComplement`:

```
CloudObject`Private`multisetComplement[a, b]
```

> {1, 2, 3, 4}

Comment: I'm not sure why when I try this I get: "Fold called with 1 argument; 2 or 3 arguments are expected" (running 10.4.1.0 on a mac).

Comment: @geordie, i am not sure but the operator form of `Fold` may have been introduced after version 10.

Answer (score 5):

Another idea for an unsorted multiset complement is to use [`Nearest`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Nearest):

```
multisetComplement[base_, rem_] := Module[{nf, tally, pos, tmp = base},
    nf = Nearest[base -> "Index"];
    tally = Tally[rem];
    pos = nf[tally[[All, 1]], {Infinity, 0}];
    tmp[[Flatten @ MapThread[Take[#1, UpTo[#2]]&, {pos, tally[[All, 2]]}]]] = Nothing;
    tmp
]
```

Your example:

```
multisetComplement[{1,2,1,3,1,3,4,5}, {6,1,3,1,5}]
```

> {2, 1, 3, 4}

This should be faster than the other answers, e.g.:

```
l1=RandomInteger[{-1000,1000},10000];
l2=RandomInteger[{-1000,1000},10000];

r1 = CountingComplement[l1, l2]; //RepeatedTiming
r2 = multisetComplement[l1, l2]; //RepeatedTiming

Sort[r2] == Sort[r1]
```

> {0.0099, Null}
>
> {0.0053, Null}
>
> True

Answer (score 4):

```
list = {1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 3, 4, 5};
del = {6, 1, 3, 1, 5};
```

Since V 13.1 there is `DeleteElements`:

```
DeleteElements[list, 1 -> del]
```

{2, 1, 3, 4}

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tested this on bigger lists but it seems to work for short sets:

```
ccomp[a_, b_] := 
 Module[
  {posall = Position[a, #] & /@ b,
   posdrop},
  posdrop = 
   Flatten@Map[Drop[#[[1]], #[[2]]] &, 
     Tally[Flatten[Select[posall, MatrixQ[#, IntegerQ] &], {1, 3}]]];
  a[[Complement[Range@Length@a, Complement[Flatten[posall], posdrop]]]]
  ]
ccomp[{1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 3, 4, 5}, {6, 1, 3, 1, 5}]
```

> {2, 1, 3, 4}

I'm sure it could be streamlined a bit.

another basic test set:

```
ccomp[{1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 1, 6, 1, 4, 8, 8, 8, 1}, {5, 1, 1, 1, 8, 8, 1}]
```

> {1, 6, 1, 4, 8, 1}

Answer (score 1):

keep the order

```
arr =
    {6, 1, 3, 1, 5} //
    Tally //
    Rule @@@ #& //
    Association

Table[
        If[!KeyExistsQ[arr, i] || arr[i] == 0,
            Sow[i]
            ,
            arr[i]--
        ]
        ,
        {i, {1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 3, 4, 5}}
    ] // Reap // Last // First
```